# Unregister all broadcast receivers registered in the activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to register them all at once with a simple code?
Or do they have to be unregistered one by one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do it one by one. An activity should not have very many, if any, and so I would not expect this to be too tedious.

Answer (score 9):

I know it's an old question but why don't you use broadcastreceivers to pick up an intent which then triggers all receivers to unregister? 
(Wanted to post something more accurate than the current answer provides)

In the responding fragments/ activities you put this:

```
public class PanicFragment extends Fragment {

  IntentFilter killFilter = new IntentFilter("your.app.name.some.awesome.action.title");

  BroadcastReceiver kill = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      context.unregisterReceiver(receiver); // The actual receiver you want to unreigster
      context.unregisterReceiver(this); // The one you just created

    }
  };
```

(Don't forget to register the receivers initially when creating the fragment/ activity)

And in your service or other activity or whatever you want this:

```
  private void callThisToUnregisterAllYourReceivers(Context context) {
    Intent killThemAll = new Intent();
    killThemAll.setAction("your.app.name.some.awesome.action.title");
    context.sendBroadcast(killThemAll);
  }
```

I hope this was in any way helpful

Comment: This is the most efficient answer, So not sure why the one above is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use another `BroadcastReceiver` to remove other broadcast receivers.

Here is what I added in my Application Class:

```
private static List<BroadcastReceiver> broadcastReceivers = new LinkedList<>();

public void addReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    mContext.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    broadcastReceivers.add(receiver);
}

public void removeReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver) {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    broadcastReceivers.remove(receiver);
}

public List<BroadcastReceiver> getAllReceivers() {
    return broadcastReceivers;
}

public void removeAllReceivers() {
    for (BroadcastReceiver receiver : getAllReceivers()) {
        removeReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```